# eventListener to be added to parent, but child element interfering

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to create this calculator, and i want that on clicking the whole key/button, the number appears on the screen. However if i click in the `h1` region of the key/button, the output is undefined. To understand the problem, try to click the key/button on the white area and then on the blue area. How can i fix that ?

```js
var evt = document.querySelectorAll(".evt");
var screenText = document.getElementById("screentext");
var show = function(e) {
 screenText.innerHTML += e.srcElement.firstChild.innerHTML;
}
for(var i = 0 ; i < 14 ; i++) {
 evt[i].addEventListener("click", show);
}
```

```css
#calcbody {
    width: 400px;
 height: 500px;
 border: 2px solid black;
}
#screen {
 width: 90%;
 height: 15%;
 border: 1px groove black;
 margin: 5%;
 text-align: right;
}
.flt {
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 height: 17%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin-left: 4%;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
 position: relative;
}
.flt2 {
 float: left;
 border: 1px solid black;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 44%;
 height: 17%;
 margin-left: 4%;
 position: relative;
}
.keys {
    text-align: center;
 padding-top: 2px;
    background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="calcbody">
      <div id="screen"><h1 id="screentext"></h1></div>
   <div id="num1" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">1</h1></div>
   <div id="num2" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">2</h1></div>
   <div id="num3" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">3</h1></div>
   <div id="num4" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">4</h1></div>
   <div id="num5" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">5</h1></div>
   <div id="num6" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">6</h1></div>
   <div id="num7" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">7</h1></div>
   <div id="num8" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">8</h1></div>
   <div id="num9" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">9</h1></div>
   <div id="num0" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">0</h1></div>
   <div id="plus" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">+</h1></div>
   <div id="minus" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">-</h1></div>
   <div id="multiply" class="flt2 evt"><h1 class="keys">*</h1></div>
   <div id="divide" class="flt2 evt"><h1 class="keys">/</h1></div>
  </div>
 </body>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: `.srcElement` is a feature of old IE browsers. The standards-compliant equivalent is `e.target`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `screenText.innerHTML += e.srcElement.firstChild.innerHTML;` to `screenText.innerHTML += e.currentTarget.innerText;`

`currentTarget` refers to the element the event is bound to, and not to the element actually clicked on. In this case, even though the user clicked on the `<h1>` element, the event bubbled up to the container div, which is the element we'd like to reference here.

```js
var evt = document.querySelectorAll(".evt");
var screenText = document.getElementById("screentext");
var show = function(e) {
 screenText.innerHTML += e.currentTarget.innerText;
}
for(var i = 0 ; i < 14 ; i++) {
 evt[i].addEventListener("click", show);
}
```

```css
#calcbody {
    width: 400px;
 height: 500px;
 border: 2px solid black;
}
#screen {
 width: 90%;
 height: 15%;
 border: 1px groove black;
 margin: 5%;
 text-align: right;
}
.flt {
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 height: 17%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin-left: 4%;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
 position: relative;
}
.flt2 {
 float: left;
 border: 1px solid black;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 44%;
 height: 17%;
 margin-left: 4%;
 position: relative;
}
.keys {
    text-align: center;
 padding-top: 2px;
    background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="calcbody">
      <div id="screen"><h1 id="screentext"></h1></div>
   <div id="num1" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">1</h1></div>
   <div id="num2" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">2</h1></div>
   <div id="num3" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">3</h1></div>
   <div id="num4" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">4</h1></div>
   <div id="num5" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">5</h1></div>
   <div id="num6" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">6</h1></div>
   <div id="num7" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">7</h1></div>
   <div id="num8" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">8</h1></div>
   <div id="num9" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">9</h1></div>
   <div id="num0" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">0</h1></div>
   <div id="plus" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">+</h1></div>
   <div id="minus" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">-</h1></div>
   <div id="multiply" class="flt2 evt"><h1 class="keys">*</h1></div>
   <div id="divide" class="flt2 evt"><h1 class="keys">/</h1></div>
  </div>
 </body>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because yours is better.

Comment: Its better to use textContent than innerText at innerText is not a W3C standard.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative, you can use [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to handle this situations.
With these CSS property you can just specify to not to listen any mouse events for `keys` elements, like this:

```
.keys {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```